# Orthogonal matrices over GF(2^t) with the first column fixed

Tags: finite-fields, linear-transformations, orthogonality

I'm interested in the existence of certain orthogonal transformations over $\mathbb F = \mathrm{GF}(2^t)$: matrices $M: \mathbb F^d \to \mathbb F^d$ for which $M^{\!\!\;\mathsf T\!\!\;} M = I_d$ over $\mathbb F$.
Specifically: let $d \geqslant 2$ be even, and $\mathbf v \in \mathbb F^d$ be such that $\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf v = 1$, where $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b$ is the dot product. Is there an orthogonal matrix $M: \mathbb F^d \to \mathbb F^d$ whose first column is $\mathbf v$?

- If $d > 1$ is odd, we cannot do this for all $\mathbf v$: for instance, if $\mathbf v = [\, 1 \;\; 1 \;\; \cdots \;\; 1\,]^{\mathsf T}$ for $d$ odd, all vectors which are orthogonal to $\mathbf v$ are also orthogonal to themselves.
- If $d = 2^m$, we can construct such an $M$ by taking the columns of the matrix to differ from $\mathbf v$ by transpositions of the coefficients: index the coefficients of $\mathbf v$ by boolean strings $x \in \{0,1\}^m$; and define $\mathbf w^{(z)} = \sum_x v_x \!\;\mathbf e_{x \oplus z}$ for each $z \in \{0,1\}^m$. We then have $\mathbf w^{(y)} \cdot \mathbf w^{(z)} = \delta_{y,z}$ in $\mathbb F$.

But for $d$ not a power of $2$ it is not obvious how to construct such an orthogonal matrix. Do there exist such orthogonal matrices over $\mathbb F = \mathrm{GF}(2^t)$, for all $d,t \geqslant 1$ and all such $\mathbf v$, provided $d$ is even?

Comment: If $t=1$ the following trick works. Assume that the given vector $v$ has $\ell$ ones. As $\ell$ is odd we have $\ell<d$. So we can select a set of $\ell+1$ coordinate positions containing those $\ell$. We get a set of $\ell+1$ orthogonal vectors by filling in all but one of those positions with ones. The remaining $d-(\ell+1)$ vectors then all have a single one and $(d-1)$ zeros. I need to think about the general case a bit more.

Comment: For $t>1$ my first idea would be to try and get the required matrix as a product of matrices of the type that have a 2x2 block of the form
$$\pmatrix{a&a+1\cr a+1&a\cr}$$ somewhere symmetrically around the diagonal, and otherwise look like the identity matrix. Here $a$ can be arbtrary. The related "generation" result is not at all clear. In particular, it is not at all clear how the requirement "$d$ even" pops out of it :-) In other words, a cool question!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you. I think that one might need at least 4x4 blocks because of the case of vectors $\mathbf v$ containing only 1s and 0s, to produce 1s in pairs. (I'm using a similar technique to deal with "unitary" matrices over Galois Rings which quadratically extend other Galois Rings.) This same trick may indeed work for GF(2^t), but sadly it is not clear that it would Hensel lift to orthogonal matrices over GR(q,q^t) for q a power of 2, unless it so happened that all of the other columns were unit vectors mod 4 as well as mod 2.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: So, my original motivation is in fact to study orthogonal matrices over GR(q,q^t) for q a power of 2... simplifying to GF(2^t) might have opened up new solutions which do not easily Hensel lift. Do you think it might be best for me to roll back my question?

Comment: Your problem may be related to that of classification of quadratic forms over a Galois ring of even characteristic. IIRC there is something generalizing the Arf invariant. I once reviewed a paper on that theme. I wasn't entirely convinced that the authors' result could not be deduced from the classical set of invariants over 2-adics from O'Meara's book. But, I'm not an expert on quadratic forms.

Comment: And, no, I don't see any need for you to roll back the question.